# Send cookie in HTTP Client IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, cookies

I tried to send cookies like this this:

```
 PUT http://localhost:8080/platform/rs2/processes/data/4252
 Accept: */*
 Cache-Control: no-cache

  Cookie: {{"TOKEN": "eyJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOiIyMTg2NTQ0Mi0zZDAxLTQ0ZWUtYTFjZC02MjI2MzllYTZhZGEiLCJjdXJyZW50VXNlcklkIjoiMjgxNDk2OTktYjNhMi00MzY1LWE4ZjAtMjYyMzljOTlmMWRkIn0"}}
```

But in fact they don't come to the server-side.

Comment: Please check the https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie for reference. Try the syntax described there.

Comment: yes, its useful

Answer (score 17):

In 2021 version of IntelliJ you can send cookies with the request like this:

```
POST url
Accept: application/json
Cookie: name=value; name2=value2
```

Ref syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

Comment: Thanks for this. I was way overthinking this, until I say your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify cookie, there is a file `http-client.cookies` used for recive cookies. If your server-side response with cookie , it would be recorded in this file.
and will be sent to your server-side automatically

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#viewingResponse

Comment: There is a need to specify a cookie if the server requires it. OP didn't ask for saving the  response cookies